# Testing for equal characteristic polynomials using a single determinant calculation

Tags: linear-algebra, determinants, spectral-graph-theory

Let $A_1,A_2$ be $n\times n$ symmetric matrices over $\{0,1\}$, and let $p_1, p_2$ be their respective characteristic polynomials over the rationals.

If $p_1 \ne p_2$, then there is some positive integer $m_0$ such that $p_1(m)\ne p_2(m)$ for every $m\ge m_0$.

What is a good upper bound on $m_0$ as a function only of $n$?

Comment: This is basically asking for an upper bound on roots of the difference of two characteristic polynomials, right?

Comment: @CommandMaster An upper bound on the real roots, yes.  I assume it is not always true that $p_1 - p_2$ has only real roots (??).

Comment: An extreme case seems to be where $A_1=I_n$ and $A_2$ is the only-$1$-matrix except for one entry being $0$. Then the difference of the characteristic polynomials has a root (slightly) bigger that $n^2/2$. So this lower bound on the worst $m_0$ might help to figure out an upper bound.

Comment: The title question does not require $m_0$ per se. If the difference polynomial $p_1-p_2$ is not identical zero, it has at most $n-1$ roots. That is, for example, evaluating $p_1,p_2$ on a random integer from $[0,2n]$ will identify $p_1\ne p_2$ with probability $>1/2$, and the larger is interval, the smaller is the error probability.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev That's correct but it isn't the question. The problem is to find a single integer $m=m(n)$ such that $|mI-A|$ uniquely identifies $p(A)$ for all $A$ in the $n\times n$ class.

Answer (score 2):

The coefficients of the characteristic polynomial are bounded by $n!$ so the coefficients of the difference are bounded by $2 n!$. The leading coefficient of the difference is integer, so its absolute value is at least $1$, and by Cauchy's bound this gives an upper bound of $2n!+1$ for the roots of the difference, so this is a good $m_0$. I'm not sure how tight this is, because each of these polynomials have fairly small roots, so a much smaller bound might be possible.